# time.asctime() V/S time.asctime(time.localtime())

Tags: python, python-datetime

What's the difference between time.asctime() and time.asctime(time.localtime()) in python? Both produce the same result with or without passing the time tuple.

Comment: time.asctime([t])
Convert a tuple or struct_time representing a time as returned by gmtime() or localtime() to a 24-character string of the following form: 'Sun Jun 20 23:21:05 1993'. If t is not provided, the current time as returned by localtime() is used. Locale information is not used by asctime().

Comment: so it is the same result in your case

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.asctime):

> time.asctime([t]) Convert a tuple or struct_time representing a time
>   as returned by gmtime() or localtime() to a string of the following
>   form: 'Sun Jun 20 23:21:05 1993'. **If t is not provided, the current
>   time as returned by localtime() is used.** Locale information is not
>   used by asctime().

(emphasis mine)

So, it doesn't make any difference, as calling it without parameter will use the output of `time.localtime` anyway.